# Using structure in reading a file, calculating, and writing into another

Tags: c, arrays, structure, file-writing, file-processing

I have an input data file called "TEST.txt". it contains id numbers, names, grades of three different exams of ten students. I'm trying to make a program that reads these input data, calculates the mean value of exams for each student, and writes again id numbers,names, averages, of students whose averages are >=45.5 into output file called "RESULT.TXT" using structures.
I think I am able to read my input data with the structure I defined. I want to know what can I do for finding the averages of exams (one,two, and three), setting the condition of writing  average values, and writing ids,names, and averages into RESULTS.TXT.
Here is my code until now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
 typedef struct student{
    char name[30];
    int id;
    int exam1;
    int exam2;
    int exam3;




}STUDENT;



int main(){
    int sum=0;
    int i=0;
    double mean[10];


    STUDENT test[10]; 
    FILE *fRead;


    fRead=fopen("TEST.txt","r+");
    if((fRead=fopen("TEST.txt","r"))==NULL){
        printf("File could not be opened\n");       
    }

    while(!feof(fRead)){


            fscanf(fRead,"%d%s%d%d%d",&(test[i].id),test[i].name,&(test[i].exam1),&(test[i].exam2),&(test[i].exam3));


            printf("\n%s\n",test[i].name);

            i++;    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) The way to write that loop is `while(fscanf(...) == 5) { printf("%s\n", test[i].name); i++;  }`

Comment: I will check it out, but why the condition==5?!

Comment: Read the [man page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb5kac8b.aspx) for `fscanf`, please, before you take one more step.

Comment: it is best (though not always used) that the definition of a struct and a typedef for that struct be separated.

Comment: the posted question is missing certain critical info.  I.E.  some example input, some expected output

Comment: regarding these two line: `fRead=fopen("TEST.txt","r+");
    if((fRead=fopen("TEST.txt","r"))==NULL){`   this is trying to open the file twice, suggest remove the first line.   Also, when a system function (in this case `fopen()` fails, the system sets `errno` with the reason for the failure.  Error messages should be output to `stderr` not `stdout`.  Suggest using: `perror( "fopen for read of TEST.txt failed");  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`   The call to `exit()` because the code cannot continue if opening the file failed.

Comment: why 10 instances of the `STUDENT` struct?  per the question only one student needs to be processed at a time.

Comment: Why the `#include <math.h>` statement?  Nothing in the posted code is using anything from that header file.  Why the `#include <string.h>` statement?.  Nothing in the posted code is using anything from the header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code:

1. is one possible way to perform the desired function:
2. cleanly compiles
3. uses fscanf() properly
4. does not use undesireable functions like `feof()`
5. is appropriately commented
6. performs appropriate error checking
7. does not include unnecessary header files
8. will handle any number of students in the input file, including 0 students

and now the code

```
#include <stdio.h>   // fopen(), fscanf(), fclose()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

#define MAX_NAME_LEN (29)

struct student
{
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN+1]; // +1 to allow for NUL terminator byte
    int id;
    int exam1;
    int exam2;
    int exam3;
};

int main( void )
{
    struct student test;

    FILE *fRead  = NULL;
    FILE *fWrite = NULL;

    if((fRead=fopen("TEST.txt","r"))==NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen for read of Test.txt failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    if( (fWrite = fopen( "RESULT.TXT", "w" )) == NULL )
    {
        perror( "fopen for write of RESULT.TXT failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    while( 5 == fscanf(fRead,"%d %" MAX_NAME_LEN "s %d %d %d",
           &(test.id),
           test.name,
           &(test.exam1),
           &(test.exam2),
           &(test.exam3)) )
    {
        printf("\n%s\n",test.name);

        float sum  = (float)test.exam1 + test.exam2 + test.exam3;
        float mean = sum / 3.0f;

        if( 45.5f < mean )
        {
            fprintf( fWrite, "%d %s %d %d %d %2.2f\n",
              test.id,
              test.name,
              test.exam1,
              test.exam2,
              test.exam3,
              mean );
        } // end if
    } // end while

    fclose( fRead );
    fclose( fWrite );

    //return 0; == not needed when returning from 'main' and value is zero
} // end function: main
```

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly but I had to write return 0; though :)

Comment: @utdlegend,   since it 'worked perfectly', please select this answer.  If you had to have the statement: `return 0;` then might I inquire as to the compiler your using and its' version number?   I know that (at least) since the C99 standard that that statement is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few changes to the code you have written, 
 1. I have used loop instead of array of structure, the constant defines the number of students to scan.

2. I have created an **fOut** pointer for RESULT.txt, which I opened in append mode.
3. I created a condition, where if mean > 45.5, the details of the students will be printed in RESULT.txt.

   P.S. I checked the program with 1 input in test file. Test it with multiple line inputs, should work fine.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   //constant for number of students, can be changed according to requirement
   #define numOfStudents 10

   typedef struct student{
   char name[30];
   int id;
   int exam1;
   int exam2;
   int exam3;
   }STUDENT;

   int main(){
       double sum=0;
       int i=0;
       double mean;

       STUDENT test; 
       FILE *fRead;

       //File pointer for output
       FILE * fOut;

       //File  for output in append mode
       fOut = fopen("RESULT.txt", "a+");       


       fRead=fopen("TEST.txt","r+");

       if(fRead == NULL)
       {
           printf("File could not be opened\n");       
       }

      //check if the file is successfully opened for appending
       if(fOut == NULL)
       {
           printf("File could not be opened for printing\n"); 
       }


       for(i; i < numOfStudents; i++)
       {  
            fscanf(fRead,"%d%s%d%d%d",&(test.id),test.name,&(test.exam1), &(test.exam2), &(test.exam3));
            //calculates mean
            sum = test.exam1 + test.exam2 + test.exam3;
            mean = sum / 3.0;

            //Condition for mean to be printed to output file
            if(mean > 45.5)               
            {
               fprintf(fOut, "%d %s %d %d %d", (test.id),test.name, (test.exam1),(test.exam2),(test.exam3 ));
               fprintf(fOut, "\n");
            }

            if(feof(fRead))
            {
               break;
            }
        }
        fclose(fRead);
        fclose(fOut);
        return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: this answer tries to access files that failed to open.  So this answer is wrong.  This answer fails to check the result of the call to `fscanf()` so will continue even if the call fails.  This answer performs an implicit conversion when calculating the variable `mean` and will truncate the result due to being an integer divide.  the function: `fprintf()` is 'expensive' and is being called an unnecessarily number of times.  the code indenting is not consistent.

Comment: this answer includes the header files: `string.h` and `math.h`.  None of the contents of those header files are used, so should not be included.

Comment: the format specifier `%s` leaves the code vulnerable to undefined behavior (if the name is greater than 29 characters long)\

Comment: this answer depends on a criteria that there is exactly 10 students in the input file.  This is an unnecessary constraint.

Comment: this line: `sum = test.exam1 + test.exam2 + test.exam 3;` does not compile

Comment: @user3629249, thank you for commenting out all the mistakes, I am new to stack overflow and have less experience with code editor here, I copied and pasted from my local machine, so there may exist problems with indentation, and also intermediate for C programming, so don;t have much experience with all those vulnerabilities